# WP - Ajax call back data printed in the console.log

Tags: php, ajax

Edit 3:
Another Ajax call in `admin_footer` testing 1244 is in the callback function
[image]

Edit 2:

These all request have been made

[image: http://localhost/wp3/wordpress/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=my_actiontesting&req=test]

Edit:

this the result of the php function inside the console log which refer to the ajax data and the alert also printed in the console.

```
function shipping()
{


?>
    <script>
        alert("test ajaxbilling name check country");
    </script>
<?php
    global $woocommerce;

    $testing = $_REQUEST['billing_first_name_post'];
    echo $testing;
}
```

[image: wp]

I literally have strange issue with Ajax in wordpress **any ajax request I make in the plugin file the call back function continues printing in the browser** **What I want to do is very simple getting the shipping address of woocommerce and add it to the total.**

```
?>
    <script>
        // since 2.8 ajaxurl is always defined in the admin header and points to admin-ajax.php
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {



            jQuery('#billing_first_name').on('focusout', function() {
                // document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (event) => {

                // document.getElementById('billing_first_name').addEventListener("focusout", function() {
                alert("Hello World!addEvtListenerToCheckoutPage2");
                if (document.getElementById('billing_first_name') !== "") {

                    var billing_first_name = document.getElementById("billing_first_name").value;

                    // We'll pass this variable to the PHP function example_ajax_request
                    my_data = {
                        // _ajax_nonce: localize._ajax_nonce,
                        action: 'shipping',
                        billing_first_name_post: document.getElementById("billing_first_name").value
                    };
                    jQuery.ajax({
                          type: "get",

                        url: "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>",
                        data: my_data,
                        success: function(msg) {
                            console.log("sucess ajax");
                            console.log(msg);
                        },
                        fail: function(msg) {

                            console.log("error ajax");
                        }
                    });
                
                }

            });
        });
    </script>
<?php
```

**The add action function to hook the action all of these code data the script contiues in the console broswer for example $_GET['billing_first_name_post']; this variable printed in the broswer and the cart total as well in the console** what are possibilites for such thing btw, I also tested on Godaddy website still the same result! what could be wrong in the plugin and the code

```
function shipping()
{


  global $woocommerce;

  $testing = $_GET['billing_first_name_post'];
  echo $testing; // prints in the console not on the back-end or the server
  $fee = 50;
  $cart_total = $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_total; 
  echo $cart_total;  // prints in the console not on the back-end or the server as well 
  $woocommerce->cart->add_fee('shipping', $fee, true, '');
   
   
}

add_action('wp_ajax_shipping', 'shipping');

add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_shipping', 'shipping');
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, is the problem that you're seeing output in the browsers dev tools console? Or something else? Try to explain using different words, and using concrete specific examples, it's very difficult to understand. Use the `Edit` link under the tags to adjust your question

Comment: Also are you sure that it's wise to name your handler `shipping`? That seems extremely generic and is likely already in use. You also don't exit/terminate your AJAX handler. **Note that this isn't a place to get help with WooCommerce, there's a very high chance your question will get closed as off-topic**

Comment: @TomJNowell Yes excatly the php function executes and runs in the browser and printing the ajax data in the console following by the ajax call data. I'll add more info and delete woocommerce part, thanks.

Comment: When I abort the JQ ajax `jQuery.ajax({` it fails

Comment: are you sure it isn't that WooCommerce already has an AJAX handler named `shopping` and your code interferes with it? `shipping` is very very generic, and just because you're using `shipping` for your code doesn't mean other people haven't already chosen and used that name for their handlers too. I suspect that if you changed it to `steve_shopping` this problem would dissapear

Comment: I made about 4 other ajax call with different actions all the php function that I receive the action from get printed in the console and even another plugin the results continues goes in the console .

Comment: I'm still a little confused, you have 2 functions named `shipping`, which one has the problem? Your second code block with the `shipping` function has comments saying it doesn't have this problem. Have you asked this in a WooCommerce community? WooCommerce questions are offtopic here and not in this stacks scope, this isn't a place to get help with WooCommerce problems

Comment: but no in woocommerce there is no such a hook called shopping or shipping and all woocommerce hook followed by `woocommerce_herethook`

Comment: You're also still not including the mandatory required `wp_die();` call at the end of your AJAX handler. This is not optional, but it is missing in your code. I'd also suggest not using the same generic name for your function

Comment: I used `wp_die()` but it's already useless and used to prevent timeout and changed the action name to `steve_shopping` also didn't work but when I try send the data with json it fails I assume could be solution that ends **mixing js with php** with using`Accept: "application/json",
                        contentType: "application/json",` in Ajax but the whole reuqest fails but I see in the url there is a failing json data

Comment: this's weird, am I the only one who gets ajax call back data in php function in the browser console?

Comment: `wp_die` isn't used to prevent timeout, you can already see the bug that not using it introduces when your data has a `0` appended to the end. Even if it doesn't solve your immediate problem, it is a hard requirement of Admin AJAX handlers. Changing the HTTP headers is not the solution either. Have you inspected the AJAX handler network responses to see which AJAX request is returning the unexpected output and where in that request? Then included that in your question? AJAX PHP handlers cannot modify what is in the browser directly, JS has to modify the DOM based on the response

Comment: Also you still haven't eliminated WooCommerce as a cause, where else are you using the `shipping` function? Or wether the output is being appended to the WooCommerce AJAX response or from somewhere else. And you still have 2 conflicting copies of the `shipping` function which is confusing. And again, have you asked this in a WooCommerce community? What you are seeing is not normal behaviour, and is not common

Comment: I had another plugin with Dropbox API integration has the same exact issue with Ajax the reponse result continues on the front-end in the action call function, 100% it's not WC,  I'm thinking of have different js file that contain ajax call with  `wp_enqueue_script` instead of having the ajax call and rest of the code in the same `index.php` file of the plugin not sure if it's gonna solve the issue. I also check the Ajax link with `wp_ajax?action=shipping&ect..` from Network and console it loads noramlly when sucess and not when it fails. Any suggestion?

Comment: The first time that I didn't notice this issue because when the call action call back php function called I was using `add_post_meta` and it was working as I remeber and I made sure of using `wp_die()` at the end of the call back action function.

Comment: By the way, This's 4th question and Yes I asked WC community and including other tags but I still didn't have solution, Overall I think I do something incompatible with Ajax and WP functionality.

Comment: note that there is nothing in your question that would cause this behaviour, so the problem must be somewhere else in the code. Nothing in your javascript would modify the HTML of the page, and your AJAX handlers calling `echo` wouldn't interfere with unrelated AJAX handlers unless there's more code we can't see. BTW do you have a link to a site with this issue?

Comment: @TomJNowell It's  plugin btw, and all the code at the `index.php` file of the plugin but the other code is normal php functions functions  like including some js libs in `wp_head` with `add_action()`

Comment: @TomJNowell
I'm developing the current plugin on my localhost also when I uploaded the plugin to the main website for testing I get the same result and issue

Comment: if you can create a minimum piece of code to reproduce this problem on another site it will help solve the problem and provide valuable information

Comment: Ok so for example making another new plugin with only one Ajax call function and test ajax is good idea? also with disabling other plugins

Comment: btw  this how I make my Ajax call in the `index.php` file of the plugin which has other functions for sure because I see most of code done with `wp_enqueue_script` that has ajax inside and so on .. 
`function addEvtListenerToCheckoutPage()
{
?>
    <script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
etc... along with Ajax call 
</script>
<?php
}`

Comment: more that I should be able to take your minimal example and install it on a fresh vanilla WP install and see the same problem you're having, with at most WooCommerce being added, nothing else, but if you can eliminate that and have the problem in its smallest, purest form

Comment: This's really weird, I installed new Wordpress created a very simple Ajax call with new actions and function that provided  in WP doc website still action call back function  **continues** prints the data in the console and when I open the link of the call which is `http://localhost/wp3/wordpress/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=my_actiontesting&req=test` the page opens normally, I'll lalso provide an image of the network after the ajax call made for making sure everything is quite good.

Comment: @TomJNowell I think I have using it wrong? as I assume I can't OR can not sure get the ajax call data from `index.php` file of the plugin while the data sent to `admin-ajax.php` because when I go to think link for example `http://localhost/wp3/wordpress/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=my_action66&whatever=1234` I find 1234 and echo testing in the page which I added in the index.php file of the plugin so I should get the real data from `admin-ajax.php` ?

Comment: your last comment doesn't make much sense to me, especially your comment on `index.php`. It's also unclear what you meant by `index.php`, wether that's a file in a plugin, a file in your theme, etc. Also can you adjust your question? You've put all your edits at the top which makes it very difficult to read, and means new people arriving at your question can't figure out what your question is. Also make sure you clearly state where each code block is, and have complete examples. It's clear that there are things you haven't shared that you consider too obvious to say that are not obvious.

Comment: I meant index.php the primary file of the plugin yes (sorry for not being specific), I found out that everything it was working normally, and because the data sent to the ajax page and I expect to be printed or executed on the current page but itprints normally on the `wp-ajax` page related to the action, but woocommerce functions someway doesn't work with the current session.